# How to I do install DB2 ODBC?

Tags: php, database

I have been trying, with no success, to install a IBM DB2 ODBC driver so that my PHP server can connect to a database. I've tried installing the db2_connect and get all sorts of problems, I tried install I Access for Linux and the RPM did not install right nor did using alien breed any useful results. I've also tried the DB2 Runtime v8.1, no success.

If I attempt to run the rpm it claims I need dependencies that I can't find in apt-get. Yum is also not very helpful as it appears I don't have any repositories installed or lists...

Running the simple RPM gives me this result in terminal:

```
# rpm -ivh iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/ln is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    /sbin/ldconfig is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    /bin/rm is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    /bin/sh is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libodbcinst.so.1()(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libodbc.so.1()(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    librt.so.1()(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) is needed by iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64
```

Using alien and running the dkpg gives me thes headaque:

```
$ alien iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm --scripts
# dpkg -i iseriesaccess_7.1.0-2_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 127664 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace iseriesaccess 7.1.0-2 (using iseriesaccess_7.1.0-2_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement iseriesaccess ...
post uninstall processing for iSeriesAccess 1.0...upgrade
/var/lib/dpkg/info/iseriesaccess.postrm: line 8: [: upgrade: integer expression expected
Setting up iseriesaccess (7.1.0-2) ...
post install processing for iSeriesAccess 1.0...configure
iSeries Access ODBC Driver has been deleted (if it existed at all) because its usage count became zero
odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 1.
Target directory is /etc
odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 3.
Target directory is /etc
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

So it seems the files installed right, well my odbc driver shows up but db2cli.ini is no where to be found.

So several questions. Is there a better alternative to connect php to db2, say an ubuntu package I can just install? 
Can someone direct me to the steps that makes my ubuntu server works well with the RPM so I can build my db2 instance?

Also remember I'm connection to an I Series remotely. I'm not using the DB2 Express C thing, even if I did try it to get the db2 php functions to work. And I don't have zend but I think I have every other package on the ubuntu repositories. Help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i do it this way:

1.
`sudo apt-get install php5-odbc alien`

2.
`alien –i –c iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.2.x86_64.rpm`

3.
`nano /etc/odbc.ini`

```
[DATASOURCE NAME] 
Description = iSeries Access ODBC Driver DSN for iSeries 
Driver = iSeries Access ODBC Driver 
System = IP ADDRESS OF YOUR iSERIES 
UserID = 
Password = 
Naming = 0 
DefaultLibraries = QGPL 
Database = YOUR DATABASE
ConnectionType = 0 
CommitMode = 2 
ExtendedDynamic = 0 
DefaultPkgLibrary = QGPL 
DefaultPackage = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512 
AllowDataCompression = 1 
LibraryView = 0 
AllowUnsupportedChar = 0 
ForceTranslation = 0 
Trace = 0 
CCSID = 1208
```